# UIAutomation with tuneup.js: Is it possible to access the label (UIStatic Text) strings using other than .value() and .name() method?

Tags: ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I have to verify the label text in an app. The actual string displayed in the app is “Elements”, but the "logElementTree();" shows name and value of that static text as “MyValue”. So please tell me how to verify the actual text displayed in the app in this case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the result of the logElementTree for the StaticText in question?

Answer (score 0):

I get it a lot where the `staticTexts()` `name()` or `value()` doesn't return when accessed by means of `logElementTree()`.

This helped me in the past.
You can maybe try storing it as a variable and check what the variable returns:

`var labelName = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().staticTexts()[0].name();`
`UIALogger.logMessage(labelName);`

`staticTexts()[0]` depending on what it's value is.  Above is just an example.

Sometimes when it is actually stored in a variable and displayed from the log it would actually give the label's value as shown in the app.